# list-style: none is not working well

Tags: html, css

I am trying to present several images in a row, even though they are all items of a list
At the moment my UI looks like this 
[image: cars in stack] instead 
of having the cars one next to the other.

My css is

```
li{
    width: 19em;

}
#tripList ul,li {
  list-style: none;
}
#tripList ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3em;

}

#tripList ul li span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 15em;
  width: 19em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

and my html code is:

```
<div id="tripList">
    <ul>
      <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
      <li >
        <span>
            <p class="remove-icon">
              <%= link_to '&times;'.html_safe, trip, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete ' + trip.trip_name + '?' } %>
            </p>

          <div class="carImg">
            <p class ="carText"><strong><%= link_to trip.trip_name, trip %></strong></p>
          </div>
          <p>
            <strong>Trippers:</strong> <%= trip.users.collect {|user| user.name }.to_sentence %>
          </p>
        </span>
      </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you tried making the li's inline-block?

Comment: Why do you use the bulleted list element `ul` if you specifically don’t want a bulleted list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#tripList ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Give that a go

Comment: When you have tried this and it works please mark it as correct. If you are still getting issues, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

`list-style: none` still puts the items under each other, you need something like `float: left` in addition. Then the items will be put beside when there is enough space.